# Como manipular ordem de Event Listeners de um elemento DOM

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Tenho um link:

```
<a href="foo" class="foo">go to foo</a>
```

Primeiro event handler (*main.js*)

```
document.querySelector('.foo').addEventListener('click', function( event ) {
   console.log(1);
});
```

Em outro script, adiciono o segundo event handler (*script.js*)

```
document.querySelector('.foo').addEventListener('click', function( event ) {
  console.log(2);
});
```

Quando executado, tenho o seguinte log:

```
1 (main.js)

2 (script.js)
```

A respeito, tenho duas dúvidas:

1. Como manipular essa ordem?
2. Como *congelar* todos os *event listeners* do link e dispará-los apenas se alguma condição for satisfeita?

Comment: Boa tarde, a resposta resolveu o seu problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pergunta 1.

Os eventos serão disparados por ordem de declaração. Eventos declarados primeiro executam primeiro, pois desta maneira o segundo evento click faz um override do primeiro, concatenando os dos métodos como se fossem um só.

Pergunta 2.

A maneira mais simples é criar uma variável auxiliar e executar a função caso ela for verdadeira, assim você pode flexibilizar o código

```
//main.js
var executar1;
//atribuir true à variável executar1 para a condição desejada
if (true)
   executar1 = true;
document.querySelector('.foo').addEventListener('click', function( event ) {
   if(executar1)
   console.log(1);
});

//script.js
var executar2;
//Não quero executar a dois, então vou deixá-la nula, valendo como false

document.querySelector('.foo').addEventListener('click', function( event ) {
   if (executar2)
     console.log(2);
   else
     console.log("não quis executar o 2");
});
```

Caso queira remover os eventos definitivamente, use o método $().off() para remover esta função

Comment: A resposta para a **pergunta 1** foi esclarecedora. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Não tem como manipular a ordem até aonde eu sei, o que você pode fazer é criar um array com todas funções, ficaria algo como:

```js
var funcoes = [
    function() {
        console.log("foo");
    },
    function() {
        console.log("Oi");
    },
    function() {
        console.log("Olá mundo!");
    },
    function() {
        console.log("Stack Overflow");
    },
    function() {
        console.log(1);
    },
    function() {
        console.log(2);
    }
];

/*
 * Reordenamento da array, coloquei uma ordem aleatória
 * Fonte: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/1518921
 */

function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex ;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {

    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;

    // And swap it with the current element.
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}

shuffle(funcoes);

var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
var j = funcoes.length;

for (var i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    foo.addEventListener('click', funcoes[i]);
}
```

```html
<button id="foo">Testar</button>
```

---

> Como congelar todos os event listeners do link e dispará-los apenas se alguma condição for satisfeita?

Pra "congelar" você terá que terá que criar um evento separado que é disparado no momento desejado, ficaria algo como:

```
var emEspera = [];

function AdicionarEspera(callback) {
    emEspera.push(callback);
}

var funcoes = [...];

shuffle(funcoes);

var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
var j = funcoes.length;

for (var i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    foo.addEventListener('click', function() {
        AdicionarEspera(funcoes[i])
    });
}

foo.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var copia = emEspera, j = emEspera.length;

    emEspera = [];//Limpa eventos em espera

    for (var i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        copia[i]();
    }
});

var test = document.getElementById("test");
```

html:

```
<button id="foo">Adicionar a lista</button>
<button id="test">Executar eventos em espera</button>
```

No momento que clicar em test então ele vai executar todos eventos em espera, após clicar ele limpa os eventos